# WordPress Development Workflow

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, themes, database, e-commerce, workflow

Hello WP DEV Community,

I understand this question has been asked ad nauseam...

I'm trying to customize a development workflow (WordPress + WooCommerce) that allows me to develop locally (to speed up development, see changes instantly in browser) -- then push to PROD.

After reading many StackExchange posts/articles/forums, this does not appear to be a trivial task.

I am hoping to gain some insights with the following question that will help me with the above goal. I am primarily trying to understand the specifics below (not necessarily how to go about designing the
actual workflow). I have a few models already in mind.  Understanding these details will assist in how I tailor my workflow -- along with some other things I hope to accomplish.

- Admin Panel:

Making WP config changes updates entries in the database only?

- Flatsome theme with UX Builder:

Making changes here appears to touch both the theme flat-files and the database (if you create new pages)?

- WooCommerce:

It appears that WooCommerce uses the WP DB/Tables (and not strictly it's own tables)?

"Products are a type of 'post,' meaning that you can migrate products between sites the same way you migrate posts. Products are stored in the database within the 'wp_posts' table, with meta data inside wp_postmeta."

I suspect that all customer accounts, comments etc are stored in the database as well (no flat-files are touched)?

The DB is live (constantly evolving) with updates by customers: new accounts, account changes, comments, orders etc.

There does not appear to be a clear (table-level) separation between WP core, Themes and WooCommerce?

Given the above, is it possible to export specific (non WooCommcerce) tables from the PROD DB and import to the DEV DB > make theme-level/WP changes > push flat-files/import specific tables back to PROD without without destroying anything in PROD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll update this answer periodically over time as I lean more about the platform. This link speaks directly to what I've mentioned above:

[The WordPress Database Structure](https://wp-staging.com/docs/the-wordpress-database-structure/)

Edit (pretty much answers everything else):

https://cadent.com/use-git-to-develop-a-wordpress-site-with-a-team-of-coders/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `wp-env` for your local env: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/env. It requires Docker to be installed.

> `wp-env` lets you easily set up a local WordPress environment for
> building and testing plugins and themes. It's simple to install and
> requires no configuration.

Comment: Thanks sir! Will check this out this week!